# Does spring encode binary data when send over network?

Tags: java, json, spring, binary

I'am creating REST API with spring boot, and planning to do client(mobile) side as well. And i'm wondering what is the best way to return and receive files(images and etc.), because when i return object with binary array as field:

```
@GetMapping("/downloadProfile/{fileId}")
        public Profile downloadProfile(@PathVariable String fileId) {
            Profile profile = profileService.findById(Long.parseLong(fileId));

            return profile;
        }
```

....

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profiles")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
    private Image image;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
    private Location location;
    ...
```

I get JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "May",
    "lastName": "Clark",
    "image": {
        "fileName": "dog.jpg",
        "fileType": "image/jpeg",
        "data": "/9j/4AAAQsk ...
```

Is it automatically encoded in Base64 or it just binary data and if so, should i store it in DB in encoded format? What is the right way to send for simple work with this on a client?